# HTML Row Border Full Table Width

Tags: html, html-table, border

I have a auto-generated HTML table with a few rows, and each row has a different number of columns.

I need to have a line separating the rows with is the full width of the table. I currently have a `border-top` which is only as long as that row, leading to different line lengths.

[Here is a Fiddle to better explain my current situation](https://jsfiddle.net/obun4jv9/1/)

I hope that it is possible to make all the lines the same length, without knowing how many columns max there are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `border-bottom` as well. This way it will always be as long as the longest line

```
td {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Here is the link:
https://jsfiddle.net/obun4jv9/2/

---

If you don't want the last row to have a border bottom, you can do it like this:

```
tr {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

tr:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/obun4jv9/3/

---

If you can set the width, this is also a possibility:

```
tr {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

tr:first-of-type {
  border-top: none
}
```

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/obun4jv9/7/

Comment: There is still a problem though when the first row does not have the maximum number of columns. https://jsfiddle.net/obun4jv9/4/

Comment: @DinoPrašo I updated my answer again, but I'm not sure if it's the best solution, because you will need to set the width of the table row

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I would recommend not setting the row to inline-block for any future visitor. I appreciate your help, but I have instead decided to rewrite the generating code to generate empty td's such that all rows are now correctly and fully populated, eliminating any need for such css hackery.